# Adding an album to a xmms2 playlist using the python lib xmmsclient

Tags: python

I'm really stuck here:
How do I add an album to the the playlist of xmms via the python library xmmsclient?

On the command-line I would use

```
    xmms2 add -o id album:"ALBUMNAME"
```

I got normal controls like play ("xmms.playback_start()")and stop (xmms.playback_stop()) working.
I read help(xmmsclient) but I could not find any information about adding albums.

Added Information:
I have read  http://git.xmms2.org/xmms2/xmms2-tutorial/tree/python. 
There I learned about the basic controls like play and stop, but I could not find anything about how to search for an album name and to add this album to the playlist.

I also had read http://git.xmms2.org/xmms2/xmms2-tutorial/tree/python, but it seems only to be a discussion of the devs which features to implement.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To have better chance to get quick answer to your question, please take a look at [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how it is best to ask a question.
And please show us, what you have tried to far!

Answer (score 1):

```
    import xmmsclient
    from xmmsclient import collections as c
    [...]
    albumName = 'example'
    album = xmmsclient.collections.Match( field="album", value=albumName )
    xmms.playlist_add_collection(album, ['tracknr'])
```

does the trick.